# Image of a group element under isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

I'm not completely sure if this proof works that an isomorphism preserves the order of elements. Here is my attempt at a proof.

> Let $f: G \to H$ be an isomorphism of groups and $x \in G$. Then
> $$\begin{align}
> x^n = e_G &\iff f(x^n) = f(e_G) \\
> &\iff f(x)^n = e_H. 
> \end{align}$$
> The second biconditional is true because $f$ is injective. The first implication implies that the order of $f(x)$ divides the order of $x$. The backwards implication implies that the order of $x$ divides the order of $f(x)$. So $\text{order}(x) =\text{order}(f(x))$.

The reason I'm not fully convinced is because most of the proofs of this fact I've read do not use a single line of biconditionals, but invoke the fact that if $|a| = n$ and $a^k = e$, then $n \mid k$.
I haven't explicitly done that, so I worry my answer makes a leap of logic.

Comment: Did you mean $\varphi$ where you typed $f$?

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: Also, did you mean $H$ where you typed $G’$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You're right, I'll fix those.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry about that. The reason I'm not fully convinced is because most of the proofs of this fact I'm read do not use a single line of biconditionals, but invoke the fact that if $|a| = n$ and $a^k = e$, then $n \mid k$. I haven't explicitly done that, so I worry my answer makes a leap of logic.

Comment: Thank you. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: The *first* biconditional uses injectivity of $f$. The second uses that $f$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the typos mentioned in the comments, the proof attempt is missing a lot of needed detail.

For example, what is $n$ when you write $x^n=e_G$. You do not say if it is the order of $x$ in $G$. It could be simply $0$, a negative integer, or any integer multiple of $\operatorname{ord}_G(x)$. In fact, a proper proof attempt will elucidate on why, in the first place, if $x^n=e_G$ for some integer $n$, it must be an integer multiple of $\operatorname{ord}_G(x)$

The definition of $\operatorname{ord}_G(x)$ is not just any integer such that $x^n=e_G$ but rather, the **least positive** integer, if it exists, such that $x^n=e_G$. You will need to make use of this fact, that if say $\operatorname{ord}_G(x)=n$, then $x^n=e_G$ but $x^k\neq e_G$ for all $1\le k\lt n$

Also, the presented attempt does not take into account the cases when $\operatorname{ord}_G(x)=\infty$, i.e., does not exist.